# EmberJS - change how an object property is displayed (not tied to route's controller)

Tags: templates, object, properties, model, ember.js

Within my Ember app, I have an object model, called Item, with a property 'price', which holds a float value, such as 20.5.  When I use the property in a template {{price}}, I would like for it to be formatted to look like so: $20.50.

This object is not the model that is tied to the controller at the route, but rather an element in an Ember Array, called items, which is a property of the model at the route.  So I have something like this in my template:

```
{{#each item in items}}
  {{item.price}}
{{/each}}
```

The problem seems pretty simple, but I can't really find a solution.  The idea is that I do not want to change the name of the property to get it to look the way I want, since I could make a computed property that formats the price property, but then I would have to use a new name in the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is write your own custom handlebars helper.
For your use case it would look something like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('formatNumber', function(value) {
  return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
});
```

And then use it in your templates this way:

```
{{#each item in items}}
  {{formatNumber item.price}}
{{/each}}
```

Please see here for a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/axucuw/6/edit).

Hope it helps.